# Laravel 5.4, show error message auth login when user not active

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

Im building auth process laravel 5.4 using default auth, my plan is I want to check some additional conditions 'user email must be activated' before log in,

I have tried to override method attempLogin to my LoginController like this

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{                
    $qLogin = [
        'user_email'        => $this->credentials($request)[$this->username()],
        'password'          => $this->credentials($request)[$this->password()],
        'active'            => 1
    ];        


    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $qLogin, $request->has('remember')
    );
}
```

the code validate as my wish, but I want to display some error messages that tell the users, he/she must active / verify their email if they want to log in

Sorry Im new for laravel, Your help will be wonderful

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add credentials function to check if users are activated. And you can modify the sendFailedLoginResponse function to customize your error message.

Path: app\Http\Controllers\LoginController

Remember to import Illuminate\Http\Request and App\User(Here is App\Models\User because I moved my User model to App\Models);

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request) {
      return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['active' => 1]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

        // Load user from database
        $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

        // Check if user was successfully loaded, that the password matches
        // and active is not 1. If so, override the default error message.
        if ($user && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $user->active != 1) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.noactive')];
        }

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }
}
```

By the way, I add a line in resources\lang\en\auth.php so I can use trans('auth.notactivated') as my error message.

```
<?php

return [
    'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',
    'notactivated' => 'This account has not been activated yet.',
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Nice one @ jack59074
 The function "sendFailedLoginResponse" needs to be restructured as follows..

```html
 protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // Load user from database
        $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();
        //dd($user);
        // Check if user was successfully loaded, that the password matches
        // and active is not 1. If so, override the default error message.
        if ($user && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $user->status != 1) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.noactive')];
        }

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to finish the answer after "follows.."?

Comment: Yes thanks see the above for the editted version....Also take note of that I have added a line in resources\lang\en\auth.php and  i change this trans('auth.notactivated')  to trans('auth.noactive')   as my error message.